# Add a auto incremental field in SharePoint survey

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list, sharepoint-survey-list

Add a auto incremental field in SharePoint survey

I need to add a serial number to my SharePoint survey to uniquely identify each row. I need to create a unique identifier based on this serial number and a combination of other fields such as year and country. Is it possible to accomplish the same via SharePoint survey? If yes, then please guide me on the same.